# Concerning siphoning water

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Problem: how much water (volume ratio) does it take on the exit side to maintain a siphon? Vertical lift 24" from water level to top of an open container? Does it have to exceed the volume on the lift side to begin the process? And how far down the exit line must it remain "solid", filling the tube, before it will start "trickling", not filling the tube? Where does the air start mixing with the water on the low side?

I am not an engineer, so please refrain from equations or physics if you can. I am trying to solve a friends pumping from a 60 gallon container problem. He thought the water may be siphoning past the pump impellers after they had stopped and I felt pretty sure that could not happen then got to thinking about what it takes to siphon. Thank you to anyone who can answer the question in a simple fashion.

Comment: Too much hand waving.  Show a diagram.  Also, this is a engineering site, so we're going to use equations when *we* think it makes sense.